# How to generate image thumbnails from network resource in advance?

Tags: scripts, nautilus, cache

After years of struggling with how to maintain my family photo collection, I have a solid process down. Our phones synchronize to the file server to a specific directory. Later, a script I wrote automatically sorts the pictures, thereby moving them from the temporary directory to their final location. The structure looks like this.

/media/vault = the main samba share
/media/vault/pictures/year/month

We have 25 years of pictures. 12 months per year. Grand total is about 44,000 images and videos.

AC wifi is great, but sometimes it's a bit "meh" when I fire up a directory and have to wait for the thumbnails to be generated. I got to wondering if I could "pre-cache" the thumbnails. I suspect this would be done via some sort of script, but I wasn't too sure where to start. I got to wondering if I could somehow trigger over CLI the "call" Nautilus would impose when you navigate to the share when it executes the act of generating thumbnails. That way I could set a depth level and target vault/pictures/* or whatever and hit every sub directory underneath. Maybe I'm looking at this with rose tinted glasses, but that's my idea anyway.

The only alternative I can think of is opening Nautilus with a slew of tabs. One for 2000/01, 2000/02, 2000/03, and repeat... for every year... every month... and let it rip overnight. I mean, I could do that -- but if I could figure out a more direct approach, I'd prefer that.

Anybody have any guesses to get started? Appreciate any responses!

Comment: I don't think that your glasses are rose tinted. The trick would be to work with thumbnail databases. The only software I know that does this in Ubuntu is `xnviewmp`, fairly easy to install the downloaded `.deb`-file from https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/ . The interface looks a bit old-style though. For each directory opened once thumbnails are added to the database and  don't need to be regenerated. If you insist on managing your photos with Nautilus I'd recommend a feature request against the used thumbnail generator package.

Comment: You don't say what format the prctures are in. If they're `.jpg`, some cameras generate the thumbnail when you take the picture. It can be extract with (after reading `man exif`) `exif --extract-thumbnail`